# Install numba 0.30.1 on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: python, python-3.x, llvm, ubuntu-16.04, numba

How do I install the current version (0.30.1) of numba for Python 3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? My version of Python is 3.5.2, and I have a barebones install of Ubuntu (server edition I think)

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install numba`

Comment: @VivekKumar Have tried. There are many dependencies that need to be setup first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so after a couple of hours of figuring things out, I've decided that this is painful enough to share and not let others figure out.

First, set up the basics: install Python 3, Git and g++

```
sudo apt install python3 git g++
```

Then get python3 packages PyPI (aka pip) and NumPy

```
sudo apt python3-pip
pip3 install numpy
```

Before we start, decide now if you want [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) now: it makes it a **LOT** easier, and you **DO** get the latest version of numba (however I don't know if you need to install dependencies before installing numba through Anaconda).

Okay, now let's get started

First add the LLVM 3.9 repositories to apt, and download LLVM

```
wget -O - http://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-3.9 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install clang-3.9 llvm-3.9-dev
```

Now get a couple of extra libraries from apt

```
sudo apt install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Add LLVM's config binary to the environment path for all users:

```
sudo echo 'LLVM_CONFIG="/usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/llvm-config"' >> /etc/environment
```

Now let's get, build and install llvmlite 0.15.0 (replace ~ with your repo directory of choice: an llvmlite folder will be created automatically under it)

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/numba/llvmlite
cd llvmlite
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

Above is where any failues will occur: hopefully all goes well (comment with issues).

Finally, install numba!

```
pip3 install numba
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install llvm-3.7 libedit-dev
sudo -H LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-3.7 pip3 install llvmlite numba
```

You need more details see this [link](https://notgnoshi.github.io/installing-numba-on-ubuntu/)

> note:you can also install by using anaconda.see this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numba/0.16.0)

Comment: This isn't the most recent version of numba: to have my program run I need jitclasses, which is only in the most recent version of numba. In addition, you still need a couple of other packages (eg zlib1g)