# Python speed up large nested array processing

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this.

```
"""
Structure
 -data[]
  -data[0] 
    -data[number, number, number, number, number, number, number]
    - ... ect X 12000
  -data[1]
    -data[number, number, number, number, number, number, number]
    - ... ect X 12000
  -data[2]
    -data[number, number, number, number, number, number, number]
    - ... ect X 12000
  -data[3] 
    -data[number, number, number, number, number, number, number]
    - ... ect X 12000
x and y are the first two numbers in each data array.
"""
```

I need to scan each item in layers 1,2,3 against each item in the first layer (0) looking to see if they fall within a given search radius. This takes a while.

```
    for i in range (len(data[0])):

        x = data[0][i][0]
        y = data[0][i][1]

        for x in range (len(data[1])):
            x1 = data[1][x][0]
            y1 = data[1][x][1]

            if( math.pow((x1 -x),2) + math.pow((y1 - y),2) < somevalue):
                matches1.append(data[0][i])
                matches2.append(data[1][x])
                continue
            else:
                continue
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: you should use numpy.

Comment: I tried to convert the array into a numpy array: data2 = np.array(data). Didn't seem to make a difference. Is there specific numpy operators I should be using to process it?

Comment: @rankind converting to an array does not make regular python operations faster. There are _loads_ of numpy methods that exist specifically for arrays.

Comment: What does your data look like? Ranges of the coordinates, how they're distributed, how large is `somevalue`, how many matches are expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should write more readable python code:

```
for x,y in data[0]:
    for x1, y1 in data[1]:
        if (x1 - x)**2 + (y1 - y)**2 < somevalue:
            matches1.append((x,y))
            matches2.append((x1,y1))
```

The you can vectorize the inner loop with numpy:

```
for x,y in data[0]:
    x1, y1 = data[1].T
    indices = (x1 - x)**2 + (y1 - y)**2 < somevalue
    matches.append(((x,y), data[1][indices]))
```

Comment: In the first example, how are x,y being extracted from data[0]? I have to reference them by position because they are not called x, y. They are always in position 0 and 1 x = data[0][i][0] y = data[0][i][1]. There is other data in the array with them. Maybe I wasn't clear enough about the data structure.

Comment: @rankind it's just sequence unpacking, the names `x` and `y` are yours to choose. If there is more stuff behind positions 0 and 1 one can use `for x, y, *dummy in data[0]:` etc. See [ħere](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: @rankind Don't forget that the for loop itself does one level of unpacking: `data[0]` is "2D", the for statement chops that up into one 1D slice at a time. And each 1D slice is then unpacked by `x, y, *catchall`.

Comment: I'm getting "python 3 > does not support starred expressions as assignments targets"

Comment: I need the structure to remain intact when I push into matches as I'm doing a lot of further processing with the other *catchall data in the array later.

Comment: @rankind What is your exact python version and how exactly did you manage to get this error?   -   Unless you are actively modifying it the structure will not be affected by looping over it or unpacking.

Comment: I've made good progress getting this to work. I failed to mention that the arrays are different lengths. Any easy way around this? "boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0"

Comment: I finally got this working how I wanted it to. SO much faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this specific problem `scipy.spatial.KDTree` or rather its Cython workalike `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` would appear to be taylor-made:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# create some random data
data = np.random.random((4, 12000, 7))

# in each record discard all but x and y
data_xy = data[..., :2]

# build trees
trees = [cKDTree(d) for d in data_xy]

somevalue = 0.001

# find all close pairs between reference layer and other layers
pairs = []
for tree in trees[1:]:
    pairs.append(trees[0].query_ball_tree(tree, np.sqrt(somevalue)))
```

This example takes less than a second. Please note that the output format is different to the one your script produces. For each of the three non-reference layers it is a list of lists, where the inner list at index k contains the indices of the points that are close to point k in the reference list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function out of this and using the [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) libray with decorator @jit(nopython=True).

also as suggested you should use numpy arrays as numba is focusing on utilizing numpy operations.

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def search(data):

  matches1 = []
  matches2 = []

  for i in range (len(data[0])):

    x = data[0][i][0]
    y = data[0][i][1]

    for x in range (len(data1[1])):
      x1 = data[1][x][0]
      y1 = data[1][x][1]

      if( math.pow((x1 -x),2) + math.pow((y1 - y),2) < somevalue):
          matches1.append(data[0][i])
          matches2.append(data[1][x])
          continue
      else:
          continue

  return matches1, matches2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Initialize
  # import your data however.
  m1, m2 = search(data)
```

The key is to make sure to only use the allowed functions supported by numba.

I have seen speed increases from 100x faster to ~300x faster.

Comment: So what was the speed increase in this case? It seems from your wording you're just throwing in the `@jit` decorator and hoping for the best.

Comment: @roganjosh  I am not sure as I don't have the data set that the user is working with. For a pixel search in a megapixel image, I was getting a very large increase in speed. Just yesterday, I converted an abel inversion code from fortran 77 to python and found it was very slow. I used numba with it and got 100x faster.

Comment: Thanks, function is already built. I'll give this a try for sure.

Comment: @rankind I'm a bit dubious about this answer because it hasn't been tested and a lot of things cannot be jitted. In this case, it would be helpful if you could provide a toy example in your question.

Comment: @KyleSwanson I'm not questioning the _potential_ speed increases from jitting; what I'm saying is that just jitting and hoping isn't a great approach. I have asked the OP to provide an example so that you could actually test this.

Comment: @roganjosh I find this an interesting bit of contention at the moment. Which I would like to explore further. May we head over to the so python chat to discuss more. room 6?

Comment: Possibly, but really you only need to look at [this](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html) for example. If anything is encountered in that function with `@jit(nopython=True)` that isn't supported, the entire function just falls back to Python speed.

Comment: Actually... if something isnt supported I believe the execution fails. I think with `@jit(nopython=False)` is when you can have the execution fall back to the normal python interpreter.

Comment: @KyleSwanson sorry, you are correct on that one, the default is to fall back and `True` raises an exception.

Comment: @roganjosh No sorry :D all good. Love to code love to learn and love to hone my skills!... this message prob against SO rules. But regardless all good!

Comment: Looks like installing Numba on Ubuntu 16.04 is a bit of a pain.

Comment: indeed... havent had to do that yet my self... but here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113233/install-numba-0-30-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a good place to use GPGPU computation.  From python you have pycuda and pyopencl depending on your underlying hardware.  Opencl can also use some of the SIMD instructions on the CPU if you don't have a gpu.
If you don't want to go down the GPGPU road then numpy or numba would also be useful as mentioned before.